# How to change the format of a fields in form view and tree view in odoo?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, odoo-13

How do you change the field based on the condition? 
Example:

model.py:

```
field_1 = field.float
field_2 = field.percentage
```

xml:

```
I don't know how to do this in XML but I will just show what I want.

form view
        name: [            ]
        commission:  [ field_1 or field ] <=  this will change the format depends on the type below.
        type: selector by default in "amount" upon checking "percentage"

tree view:
       <field name="name"/>
       <field commission="field1 or field2"> <= I don't know how to code this.
       <field type="type"/>
```

This is my code model:

```
class architecture_page(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    @api.constrains('architect_com_type', 'architect_commission')
    def _validate_commission(self):
        for field in self:
            if field.architect_com_type == 'Percentage':
                if (field.architect_com_type > 100) or (field.architect_com_type <= 0):
                    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
                        "Percentage fields must be less than equal to 100 or greater than 0")
```

This is my XML code:

```
<odoo>
    <record id="view_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Architecture</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//page[@name='order_lines']" position="after">
                <page string="Architect and Interior Designer">
                    <tree string="Architect and Interior Designer"
                          editable="bottom"
                    >
                        <control>
                            <create name="add_architect_control" string="Add a architect"/>
                        </control>

                        <field name="architect_id"/>
                        <field name="architect_commission"/>
                        <field name="architect_com_type"/>
                    </tree>
                </page>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

I am trying to create an editable tree view that is similar to the order lines in a quotation where we can add a new unit or products in it.

[image]

But mine is not like that.

[image]

Encounter some errors:

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 392, in _check_xml
    self.postprocess_and_fields(view.model, view_doc, view.id)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 952, in postprocess_and_fields
    fields_def = self.postprocess(model, node, view_id, False, fields)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 882, in postprocess
    fields.update(self.postprocess(model, f, view_id, in_tree_view, model_fields))
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 882, in postprocess
    fields.update(self.postprocess(model, f, view_id, in_tree_view, model_fields))
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 882, in postprocess
    fields.update(self.postprocess(model, f, view_id, in_tree_view, model_fields))
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 803, in postprocess
    xarch, xfields = self.with_context(
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 964, in postprocess_and_fields
    self.raise_view_error(message, view_id)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 592, in raise_view_error
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Field `architect_ids` does not exist

Error context:
View `architect.page.view`
[view_id: 846, xml_id: n/a, model: sale.order, parent_id: 756]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 712, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 674, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 577, in _tag_record
    record = model._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\models.py", line 4067, in _load_records
    records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\models.py", line 3981, in _load_records_create
    return self.create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-32>", line 2, in create
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\api.py", line 336, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 473, in create
    return super(View, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in create
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\api.py", line 336, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\models.py", line 3762, in create
    fields[0].determine_inverse(batch_recs)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\fields.py", line 1114, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 299, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 490, in write
    return super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\models.py", line 3551, in write
    real_recs._validate_fields(set(vals) - set(inverse_fields))
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\models.py", line 1167, in _validate_fields
    check(self)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 394, in _check_xml
    raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating view"), tools.ustr(e)))
odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: ('Error while validating view\n\nField `architect_ids` does not exist\n\nError context:\nView `architect.page.view`\n[view_id: 846, xml_id: n/a, model: sale.order, parent_id: 756]', None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\http.py", line 619, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\http.py", line 309, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\http.py", line 664, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\http.py", line 345, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\service\model.py", line 93, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\http.py", line 338, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\http.py", line 910, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\http.py", line 510, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "d:\dev\odoo-13.0\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1324, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "d:\dev\odoo-13.0\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1312, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\api.py", line 387, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\api.py", line 374, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-65>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 72, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 629, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 573, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 417, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 225, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 68, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 736, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 803, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 715, in parse
    pycompat.reraise(
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 13, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 712, in parse
    self._tag_root(de)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 674, in _tag_root
    f(rec)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 577, in _tag_record
    record = model._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\models.py", line 4067, in _load_records
    records = self._load_records_create([data['values'] for data in to_create])
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\models.py", line 3981, in _load_records_create
    return self.create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-32>", line 2, in create
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\api.py", line 336, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 473, in create
    return super(View, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in create
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\api.py", line 336, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\models.py", line 3762, in create
    fields[0].determine_inverse(batch_recs)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\fields.py", line 1114, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 299, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 490, in write
    return super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\models.py", line 3551, in write
    real_recs._validate_fields(set(vals) - set(inverse_fields))
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\models.py", line 1167, in _validate_fields
    check(self)
  File "D:\dev\odoo-13.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 394, in _check_xml
    raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating view"), tools.ustr(e)))
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Error while validating view

Field `architect_ids` does not exist

Error context:
View `architect.page.view`
[view_id: 846, xml_id: n/a, model: sale.order, parent_id: 756]
None" while parsing file:/d:/dev/odoo-13.0/custom/architect_page/views/architect_page.xml:1, near
<odoo>
    <record id="view_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">architect.page.view</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//page[@name='order_lines']" position="after">
                <page string="Architect and Interior Designer">
                    <field name="architect_ids">
                        <tree string="Architect and Interior Designer" editable="bottom">
                            <control>
                                <create name="add_architect_control" string="Add a architect"/>
                            </control>
                            <field name="architect_ids"/>
                            <field name="architect_commission"/>
                            <field name="architect_com_type"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </page>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

model:

```
class ArchitectPage(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    architect_ids = fields.One2many(string='Architect',
                                    comodel_name='res.architect', inverse_name='sale_id')
```

res_architect:

```
class ResArchitect(models.Model):
    _name = 'res.architect'
    name = fields.Char('name')
    architect_com_type = fields.Selection(string='Commission type',
                                          selection=[('percentage', 'Percentage'), ('float', 'Float')])
    architect_commission = fields.Float(string='Architect Commission')
    sale_id = fields.Many2one(string='sale', comodel_name='sale.order')

    # put your constraint here
    @api.constrains('architect_com_type', 'architect_commission')
    def _validate_commission(self):
        for field in self:
            if field.architect_com_type == 'Percentage':
                if (field.architect_com_type > 100) or (field.architect_com_type <= 0):
                    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
                        "Percentage fields must be less than equal to 100 or greater than 0")
```

Comment: Add a computed field in your model called commision, then put your logic in there (choosing which field to show in commission depending on the type), the put your new field in the form/tree view. another solution would be to put both fields in xml with attrs="{'invisible':[('type', '=', 'amout')]} in one field  and {'invisible':[('type', '=', 'percentage')]}  on the other, you can do this for the form view, but wont work with the tree view

Comment: Hi MJana, I have updated my questions. Please see details above. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a form view `view_order_form`, you need one2many/many2many field, to make a tree view inside it, you need to create a new module 'res.architect' or something, and link it to sale.order module using one2many, then you can make a tree view of architects in your tab.

res_architect.py

```
from odoo import models, fields

class ResArchitect(models.Model):
    _name = 'res.architect'
    name = fields.Chat('name')
    architect_com_type = fields.Selection(string='Commision type',selection=[('percentage','Percentage'),('float','Float')])
    architect_commission = fields.Float(string='Architect Commission')
    sale_id = fields.Many2one(string='sale', comodel_name='sale.order')

    # put your contraint here
    @api.constrains('architect_com_type', 'architect_commission')
    def _validate_commission(self):
        for field in self:
            if field.architect_com_type == 'Percentage':
                if (field.architect_com_type > 100) or (field.architect_com_type <= 0):
                    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
                        "Percentage fields must be less than equal to 100 or greater than 0")
```

then in your sale order model

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    architect_ids = fields.One2many(string='Architect', 
    comodel_name='res.architect', inverse_name='sale_id')
```

then update your view like this:

```
<odoo>
    <record id="view_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Architecture</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//page[@name='order_lines']" position="after">
                <page string="Architect and Interior Designer">
                    <field name='architect_ids'>                    
                        <tree string="Architect and Interior Designer"
                              editable="bottom">
                        <control>
                            <create name="add_architect_control" string="Add a architect"/>
                        </control>

                        <field name="architect_commission"/>
                        <field name="architect_com_type"/>
                    </tree>
                        </field>
                </page>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

I hope this helps you, keep me posted if you need any further help!

Comment: It is kind of weird. the compiler cannot find architect_id which I've already changed the name from ids to id and add some security model and also adding it in __init__.py the res_architect.py in the model.


Field `architect_id` does not exist

Error context:
View `architect.page.view`
[view_id: 842, xml_id: n/a, model: sale.order, parent_id: 756]

Comment: Oops the field <field name="architect_ids"/> should not be inside the tree view, you can replace it by <field name="id"/> if you want to show the id on your tree view

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a possible to get all information from the architect table? because I tried to get the first_name and yes, it does not recognize or similar with architect_ids

Comment: yes, you can get all the field in res.architect table in the same way we got `architect_commission` and `architect_com_type`, you can mark my answer as accepted if it does answer your question. I'm here if you need any further help

Comment: I tried to use this under res_architect.py, architect_name = fields.Many2one('architect.form', string="Architect Name") But it only gets the id, not the name itself and  I think also creating a new field full_name in architect table. Thank you so much.

Comment: that's another question, you may create an other thread for that